# What does "let her down" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "let her down" mean in the song below:

> She knows, she knows
>   That I never let her down before.

Comment: and what does "before" means in here?

Comment: "Before" means "previously" here.

Comment: Please try to look things up in a dictionary before asking here. Both these words can be easily found in any dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: Disappoint

"She knows, she knows
That I never [disappointed] her before."

Source:  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/let+down